# A word(not phrase) for 'celebrating something without understanding'

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, epithet-requests

A few examples :

1. People who can code in a programming language but don't understand algorithms, data structures, and other concepts but 'celebrate' Programmer's Day
2. Have a degree in engineering but have professions barely, remotely connected to engineering, yet, celebrating 'Engineers Day'
3. People who don't own an iPhone, even if they do, they are unaware of how it is better than other phones or aren't aware of all the features of iPhone but go bonkers about the iPhone 8 event

Facade, pompousness and so on came to my mind but the dictionary definition doesn't match with the above behaviour which is a mixture of ignorance, impatience, falsehood and desperation for an identity, an edge over others etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a diatribe disguised as a question.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like they're a [wannabe](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wannabe). Desperate to be part of an in-group, but lacking the skills or acceptance to qualify.

Comment: But what about a person who has an iPhone, an engineering degree ? Wannabe makes some sense for a coder who thinks he's a programmer. 'Wannabe' is a person who wants to become someone for which he's not qualified but a coder or a degree holder 'BELIEVES' that he is what he is really not

Comment: It sounds like you are after the Dunning-Kruger effect (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect); people who have delusions of competency. I can't think of a single word to describe someone like this, but maybe the link will help?